# Getting span element to wrap within td

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell defined as such:

```css
td {padding-left: 300px} /* for easier demo when testing */
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="payment-type-label">Payment Type: 
      <span class="payment-type">Computer Payment</span>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the `span` to wrap on to a new line rather than overflow under the text:

So rather than:

```
Payment Type: Computer
Payment
```

I get the word Payment under Computer?

```
Payment Type: Computer
              Payment
```

Comment: tried add display:inline-grid;  to your <td> or you can set the span to display:block;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly tables are for tabular data - although your content maybe tabular, you are not using the table correctly, you should either get rid of your table, or use it correctly:

The below separates the column header and column details

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" class="payment-type-label">Payment Type: </th>
    <td>
      Computer <br /> Payment
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If that is not possible, then I would remove them table as it is not semantically correct and use a flex approach:

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  width:200px;   /* for test so content wraps */
}

.row .title {
  padding-right: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;  /* keep title on one line */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="title">Payment Type:</div>
  <div class="content">Computer Payment</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

could simply just add `<br />` -

```
<td class="payment-type-label">Payment Type: 
<span class="payment-type" >Computer <br /> Payment</span>
</td>
```

EDIT

could try this -

```
.payment-type {display:block;width:80px;}
```

by setting a width with `display:block` it will force the text to wrap

example - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smorris1900/0n6gyyxa/)

Comment: Content is dynamic and this needs to be a CSS solution